# How to test dispatched react function using Jest

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to unit test a function which makes an async call using an Axios helper instance. I have attempted multiple ways of trying to unit test this but I can not seem to find any material online which has helped. I've been stuck on this problem for a few days which is frustrating so any help would be appreciated! Below are the Axios Helper file (api.js)

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API = (token = null) => {
let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key': process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HEADER_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
}

if (token) {
    const tokenHeader = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
    headers = { ...headers, ...tokenHeader }
}

const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL

const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: url,
    headers
})

return API
}

export default API
```

**mocked API**

```
export default {
post: jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        data: {}
    })
),
get: jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        data: {}
    })
)
}
```

**action file**

```
export const initiate2FA = (destinationValue) => async () => {
  const twoFactorAuth = destinationValue
  const res = await API().post('/foo', {
      Destination: twoFactorAuth
})

return res
}
```

**Action.test.js**

```
import API from 'api/api'
import { initiate2FA } from 'actions/userActions'

jest.mock('api/api')
const mockedAxios = API
const dispatch = jest.fn()

describe('Initiate2FA function', () => {
  it('bar', async () => {
      mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ status: 200 }))

      const t = await dispatch(initiate2FA('test@test.com'))
      console.log(t)
  })
})
```

My issue with the above test file is that it returns an anonymous function and I do not know how to handle this to pass the unit test. The goal of the test is to make sure the function is called. I am not sure if I am approaching this the correct way or should change my approach.

Again, any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Mocking an API call is something you can mock on your own React component, instead of a function, and the best option would be to not mock anything on your component. [Here you can read all about why you should not mock your API functions](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch). At the end of the article, you're going to find a library called **[Mock Service Worker](https://mswjs.io/)** which you can use for your purpose.

The way you declare you have an actual HTTP called that needs to be mocked would be something like this:

```js
rest.get('/foo', async (req, res, ctx) => {
  const mockedResponse = {bar: ''};
  return res(ctx.json(mockedResponse))
}),
```

If you just need to unit test a function, you can still use Mock Service Worker to resolve the HTTP request, and then test what happens after that. This would still be your first choice. And the test would look like:

```js
// this could be in another file or on top of your tests.
rest.get('/foo', async (req, res, ctx) => {
  const mockedResponse = {bar: ''};
  return res(ctx.json(mockedResponse))
}),

// and this would be your test
describe('Initiate2FA function', () => {
  it('bar', async () => {
      const res = await initiate2FA('test@test.com');
      
      expect(res).toBe({bar: '');
  })
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I've implemented as suggested but when I run the test i get 'Recieved: [Function Anonymous]'. Do you know the solution for this?

Comment: As I cannot see the full code, I cannot provide a solution. Could you replicate your issue in a codesandbox or similar?